# Is there an integral formula for the degree of a holomorphic embedding of the Riemann sphere into projective space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I feel that this may be related to the Riemann Roch theorem or Riemann Hurwiz formula but I'm not sure how.  If you could provide a good reference and what to look for I would be very grateful.

Comment: What is the data that you want your formula to be in terms of?

Comment: You have a map $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$, I was thinking there might be a formula using the differential of this map or something of that nature.

Comment: What I was getting at is that there are many different such maps, with different degrees. Indeed, Mohan explained the situation for $n=3$ in comments to one of your previous questions.

Comment: Thanks, yes that was useful to me.  I'm talking about if you have a specific map, and you want to find the degree using an integral formula.  I think I more or less understand Mohan's previous answer at this point.

Comment: I'm reading Griffiths and Harris and I think I might be looking for something related to the Wirtinger theorem (pg. 171 of G and H).  I'm going to think about it some more but this is looking helpful.